# Swift: What does "completionHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)" mean?

Tags: ios, swift, void, completionhandler

Can someone explain what **completionHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)** means?

For instance it appears when requesting camera access:

```
AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.depthData, completionHandler: (<#T##(Bool) -> Void#>))
```

I usually do this to check if access was granted or not:

```
func requestCamera() {
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) { (response) in
            if response {
                print("true")
            } else {
                print("denied")
            }
        }

    }
```

Obviously I do stuff there, but that doesn't matter here. I just want to understand what **((Bool) -> Void)** means and why I have to use the completion handler here. With other functions I can just set the handler to nil, but in this case it expects a response in some way.

So what does this mean?

Comment: Note:  This is using *trailing closure syntax*.  The closure following the call is being provided as the last argument to the call.  Everything between `{ (response) in` and `}` is a closure which takes a `Bool` and returns nothing.  This closure is given to `requestAccess` as `completionHandler` and when the function calls `completionHandler(true)` or maybe with `false` your closure will will execute.

Comment: this completion handler does not expect a response _from_ you, it will _notify_ you after the user of your app made their mind up about granting / denying permission (`Bool`) to capturing videos – and you obviously want to get a feedback about that because your app next action depends on the user's decision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read Closures section of the Swift [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).

It is a completion closure that gets executed when the `AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess` is finished with  requesting access from the user. It has one `Bool` parameter that is true/false according to whether the user granted the access or not. It is not optional, so you have to provide some closure - that was a decision of the `AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess` author, and it makes sense - if you are requesting the access, you are requesting it because you want to use `AVCaptureDevice`. Therefore the author expects you to react to completing the `requestAccess` in some way.

Comment: Thanks. I understand this now. But why can't I use the same structure as above for  `PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization` ? If I use "response" I get this error: **PHAuthorizationStatus' is not convertible to 'Bool'** . In that case I just use `if status == .authorized {...` . Isn't this the same structure?

Comment: @RjC simply because the `AVCaptureDevice` has closure with type `(Bool) -> Void`, and `PHPhotoLibrary` has closure with type `(PHAuthorizationStatus) -> Void`.. they accept different types, so in one case the parameter is a `Bool` value, in the other `PhAutorizationStatus` (see documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phphotolibrary/1620736-requestauthorization)

Comment: Thanks so much! That helped a lot to understand whats going on here!

Answer (score 2):

Closure expression syntax has the following general form:

```
{ (parameters) -> return type in
    statements
}
```

The parameters in closure expression syntax can be in-out parameters, but they can’t have a default value. Variadic parameters can be used if you name the variadic parameter. Tuples can also be used as parameter types and return types.

**completionHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)** this means that you'll get a Boolean value in your closure and it will return nothing(Void). Just like a method.

You can find this more about in [Apple's documentation about closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

Comment: Closures have become a bigger part of iOS development(I can't speak for macOS but i'm assuming there as well).  Most of the time when you see/create a closure it is because of async programming.  You can think of it as the 'done' section of an ajax call, or kind of like a finally statement to a try catch.

Answer (score 2):

`(Bool) -> Void` means a closure take accepts a `Bool` as a argument and return a `Void` (i.e. nothing).

You provide a completion handler because `requestAccess` execute asynchronously. When the user has decided what permission to give your app, iOS will call the completion handler to continue execution of your program.

Answer (score 1):

The majority of closures are used to handle some information that will be available later, for instance, a back end request that will take some seconds to respond, or even some action is required before some operation.

When you call a function that has a completion handler, it's the same as asking for something in the future, that will execute when the information is available, it's a great solution for asynchronous stuff or when you need to wait for some action, and then continue when you got the necessary data.